# Why with wifi I can connect but not with my mobile data

Tags: flutter, connection, wifi

Hello I have a problem this morning that I did not meet. with wifi I can connect with the application but not with my mobile data. Can anyone help me? Here is the content of

```
AndroidManifest.xml



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <application
        android:label="FACTURA"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android API 28 and iOS 9, these platforms disable insecure HTTP connections by default.

You can use this code:
Add *network-policy* at your meta-data in *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
>
> ....
>
> <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
> android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
> ```

Allowing cleartext connection for *debug builds*:
Look at: $project_path\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

You can see this documentation:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android